# How i can show default values of each column in ERD that generated by powerdesiner

Tags: erd, datamodel, powerdesigner

I want to show default value of each column in my ERD.How I can do that ?
I don't see something about it in content tab in symbol format windows. Only in preview tab in table properties, I can see default values for columns in generated SQL. the Power designer version is 16.6.

Comment: `Tools > Display Preferences > Table > Advanced > Columns > List columns: > Select > (Select Attributes) Default Value` ?

Comment: @pascal Thank you . Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the attributes displayed for columns under `Tools > Display Preferences > Table > Advanced > Columns > List columns:`

Use `Select > (Select Attributes) Default Value` to add the default value.

This list of attributes does not provide long text attribute, like Description. For these, you might be able to work a solution using calculated attributes.